# Ionic open android camera with ng-file-upload input button

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, android-webview, ng-file-upload

I'm making an app using Ionic. It's almost done, but there is one problem. I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload files from the device. From iOS it asks if I want to upload from my gallery, or take a picture with the camera. From Android, it only asks from gallery, no camera option is showed.

I have read the whole documentation of ng-file-upload, and all the open and closed issues. None of them helped though.

I am using the following code:

`<div class="thumbnail_box col col-25" ngf-select="addImage(picFile)" ngf-fix-orientation="true" ngf-capture="camera" ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*">`

Tried a lot of different tags, such as:
`ngf-capture="camera"`
`capture="camera"`
`no tag at all`

If have also tried using a `<button>` and `<input type="file"...>` istead of a `div`, which also don't work..

I have also tried it with, and without the [Crosswalker-project](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview). Doesn't seem to make any difference.. 
When I visit one of the [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/) of ng-file-upload on my browser on my Android phone, and press on the 'choose file' button, it does show the camera option..

Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Seems I had to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to the AndroidManifest xml file